# Class Cast Exception when casting double

Tags: java, casting, double, joptionpane

I tried running the following code. It compiles, but throws a ClassCastException. I would be really glad if anyone can help me figure out why.

```
double costprice = 0;
Object[] possibilities = null;
costprice = (double) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    alphaPOS,
                    "Cost Price:",
                    "Enter Values",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    possibilities,
                    "");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`returns a `Object` (credits to @SeleenVirtuose) which cannot be cast to a `double`, use `Double.parseDouble()` to parse a String as a double.

```
costprice = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                alphaPOS,
                "Cost Price:",
                "Enter Values",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null,
                possibilities,
                ""));
```

Also, you can all of this on one line

As you are declaring the `double` variable and then setting straight away, you might as well declare it and assign the new value in one line

```
double costprice = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            alphaPOS,
            "Cost Price:",
            "Enter Values",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null,
            possibilities,
            ""));
```

Also, as the `possibilities` variable is null, just pass `null` as the parameter (unless you have changed the variable somewhere else)

```
double costprice = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            alphaPOS,
            "Cost Price:",
            "Enter Values",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null,
            nulll,
            ""));
```

Comment: The used method returns an `Object` that the user selected from the provided `Object[]`. It still is - of course - not a `double`.

Comment: @ShifaTsar If you feel that I answered your question adequately, please mark it as the correct answer so people know your question has been answered!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose What would return a double then in a showInputDialog?

Comment: @ShifaTsar There are no methods that would, try looking through the Java documentation to figure out what methods you need for certain applications: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Comment: @ShifaTsar You could provide an `Object[]` whose elements are all `Double`s (the wrapper type). In that case you could cast the return value to `Double` and call the method `doubleValue()` on it for retrieving the needed `double`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose ah, but i want the user to input the variables, and not give a list. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

[JOptionPane.showInputDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object%29) returns an Object, which can't be cast to a double.

Comment: The used method returns an `Object` that the user selected from the provided `Object[]`. It still is - of course - not a `double`.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose my mistake, I got it mixed up with another variant of showInputDialog, which does return a String.